# In Jquery need to align record

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am using bootstarp class. Not able to align sub Mealoption into one single line for each MealOption.

```
for (var i = 0; i < MealOption.length; i++) {
    mealoptions += "<div class=col-md-11>" + "<div class=col-md-4>" + MealOption[i].MealoptionName + "</div>" + "</div>";
    for (var j = 0; j < MealOption[i].sMealOption.length; j++) {
        if (MealOption[i].sMealOption[j].IsTexture == true)
        {
            mealoptions += "<div class=col-md-4>"+"</div>"+"<div class=col-md-7>" + MealOption[i].sMealOption[j].TextureLevel + " , " + "</div>" ;
        }
    }
    //Display Results according to condition
}
```

[image: Please refer the link]

Any help will be appreciated . Thanks in advance

Comment: What is you current O/P and What is your Expected O/P. Please give more explanation

Comment: As you see in the snapshot 'clear Feed' And 'cle Fee' is coming line below Meat texture. those are sub items of Meat texture. i want them in one line with meat Texture.

Comment: @Downvoter if you thing this question or any question is not good enough to answer. please not discourage others by down doting or at least write your comment.  For you it may looks silly question but for others its an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your code with

```
        for (var i = 0; i < MealOption.length; i++)
        {
            mealoptions += "<div class=col-md-11>" + "<div class=col-md-4>" + MealOption[i].MealoptionName + "</div>";
            for (var j = 0; j < MealOption[i].sMealOption.length; j++)
            {
                if (MealOption[i].sMealOption[j].IsTexture == true)
                {
                    mealoptions += "<div class=col-md-7>" + MealOption[i].sMealOption[j].TextureLevel + " , " + "</div>";
                }
            }
            mealoptions += "</div>";
            //Display Results according to condition
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution .